# Typescript conversion from original interface to another one which is omitted from original

Tags: typescript, interface

I've googled this, found some examples but neither are working for me.

So lets say I have the following code

```
// third party API response
interface Original {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  pga: number;
}

// the data I need
interface OriginalPartial extends Omit<Original, "pga"> {
  createdAt?: Date;
}

const originalData: Original[] = [
  {
    id: "1234-5678",
    name: "John",
    age: 19,
    pga: 3.4,
  },
  {
    id: "1234-5679",
    name: "Mike",
    age: 19,
    pga: 4.4,
  },
  {
    id: "1234-5670",
    name: "Steve",
    age: 19,
    pga: 5.0,
  },
];

const neededData: OriginalPartial = originalData[0];
```

when I do this I still see neededData.pga, and I get no errors. Is there a way to remove not needed props (in this case pga) without using lodash.omit or lodash.pick?

Comment: You should get an error, `console.log(neededData.pga)` this should not compile, since `pga` property is omitted. Are you sure about getting no error? I've just tested in VS code 4.3.5 Typescript compiler and got compile error. Just in case this `console.log(originalData[0].pga);` gives no error as is expected, since data types are different for `originalData` and `neededData`

Comment: Typescript only adds types, it will not alter any runtime. It may add polyfill, but nothing else.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov yeah it does, I was copy pasting whole lot of code around so I forgot .pga, but basically when I write only neededData it doesn't complain so I wrote I'm getting no errors.